# Docker hub keeps timing out and retrying on large image layer until failure

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have an unavoidably large docker image layer (2.4GB). When I push the image to my paid docker hub registry account (support is non-existent on this issue), it pushes at about 1MB per second, and about half way through times out and starts re-trying. It does this about 5 times before giving up.

I used to be able to push the layer--I think perhaps I am at some threshold where, depending on the docker upload speed, sometimes I timeout and sometimes I don't. It seems like an old problem https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/469 but solution is inconclusive.

Here's what times out:

```
docker push metalaureate/yard-stats:latest
The push refers to repository [docker.io/metalaureate/yard-stats]
68aa0af45ea8: Preparing 
68aa0af45ea8: Pushing [==>                                                ]  137.7MB/2.492GB
c8902f34de3c: Layer already exists 
239c6e8c7ca5: Layer already exists 
c1c31e2fe28c: Pushed 
88176e364a30: Pushing [==========>                                        ]  203.9MB/970.9MB
981eff82d876: Layer already exists 
c11aa0d1cbc2: Layer already exists 
8bc59dd7b32b: Layer already exists 
de9ab7da6a52: Layer already exists 
86cf19f333cc: Layer already exists 
4b8e4d51fbe2: Layer already exists 
cf5b3c6798f7: Layer already exists
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM andrejreznik/python-gdal:stable

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev && apt-get install -y curl  nginx


WORKDIR /
COPY ./ /
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt


CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

EDIT:
I tried encapsulate the 2.4GB layer in a separate image and derive my yard-stats image from that, on the theory that docker wouldn’t try to push up the image that it was deriving from, but that didn’t help.

Comment: Considering you have a paid docker hub registry, did you try contacting their customer support?

Comment: Yeah, there isn't much by way of support. Just FAQs.

Comment: https://success.docker.com/article/commercial-support-service-levels
  
either way I would ask this question within docker forums